# Performing mandatory cleanup operations before kill of app

Tags: java, android

In my Android app I perform few resource intensive operations. I have to close/cleanup these at all times before app is killed. As I understand `onStop()`/`onDestroy()` life cycle methods not guaranteed to execute during the kill of an app. Hence, it is not trustworthy to put close/cleanup operations in these methods. What are the best alternatives that Android provides to achieve this functionality? Thanks.

Comment: You can use `finally` block to close your resource.

Comment: In which life cycle method to put `finally` block ?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/finally.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `onPause` instead of `onStop, onDestroy`. It is guaranteed to be called.

Answer (score 1):

What I suggest is to override onDestroy() on your main activity to execute the code when your app get destroyed, or onStop() to execute the code when the user exits your app.

onDestroy()will be called before the activity is destroyed.It could be called either because the activity is finishing (someone called finish() on it), or because the system destroying instance of the activity to save space. These two scenarios can distinguished by using isFinishing() method.

on the other hand onStop() is called when the activity is no longer visible to the user. This may happen because it is being destroyed, or because another activity has been resumed.Followed either by onRestart() if the activity is coming back to interact with the user or by onDestroy() if this activity is going away.

```
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    // The activity is no longer visible i.e is it stopped now
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    //It is about to destroyed
}
```

Comment: `onStop()` and `onDestroy` are not guaranteed to run till the end. They may execute only part of the method. After killing of the app, android app process may terminate at any time.

Answer (score 1):

onPause() and onStop() will not be invoked if finish() is called from within the onCreate() method. This might occur, for example, if you detect an error during onCreate() and call finish() as a result. In such a case, though, any cleanup you expected to be done in onPause() and onStop() will not be executed.

Although onDestroy() is the last callback in the lifecycle of an activity, it is worth mentioning that this callback may not always be called and should not be relied upon to destroy resources. It is better have the resources created in onStart() and onResume(), and have them destroyed in onStop() and onPause, respectively.

See the Android developer’s guide for more information about the activity lifecycle.
https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html